# All countries and US states from google api

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, google-maps-api-3

Is there a google API for displaying list of all countries in the world and also an API for displaying list of all states in US? I know of an autocompleter api (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?sensor=false&key=&input= ) to display places but not specific only to countries and US states

Comment: Not to my knowledge with Google. You probably can find another API though. Autocomplete allows you to biase the results to specific bounds and the *regions* type will instruct the API to return localities, countries, administrative areas, etc. but that won't get you a list of countries or states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ressources for this kind of data, e.g. fusionTables:

countries: https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=12e2VhiXyMzHWDl6aponObHH_gvlMDoac9RTrcJ0#map:id=6

US-states: https://www.google.com/fusiontables/data?docid=1bkBD2aQ_OxPZxFQ-KD2l5-2Th5S-J0voBSmd_OI#map:id=20

The data may be requested via AJAX, see https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/sql-reference

Comment: This link no longer works for AJAX